# Clockwork / Clockworkd produces 'No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, clockwork

I'm running clockwork in the background using Clockworkd. If I just run clockwork, it executes the rake command successfully. If I run it via clockworkd, it produces an error. I'm not sure why it isn't working. Any advice / suggestions would be appreciated.

**Starting clockworkd**

```
RAILS_ENV=production clockworkd -c lib/clock.rb start --log
```

**The error**

```
I, [2013-09-05T17:53:01.035923 #2580]  INFO -- : Triggering 'Get Updates'
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/Users/lukesmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:632:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/lukesmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/lukesmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/lukesmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/lukesmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/Users/lukesmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/lukesmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/lukesmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/lukesmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/lukesmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

**clock.rb**

```
require 'clockwork'
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot', __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

include Clockwork

handler do |job|
  puts "Running #{job}"
end

every(1.hour, 'Get Updates') { `rake get_updates` }
```

Answer (score 0):

The process running your `rake get_updates` task may not be in the same working directory as your Rakefile is located.

You could either `Dir.chdir '/dir/containing/Rakefile/'`, or else explicitly pass the path to the Rakefile using the `-f` option:

```
every(1.hour, 'Get Updates') do
  Dir.chdir '/dir/containing/Rakefile/'
  `rake get_updates`
end
```

Comment: I linked to the file, but it then threw the error 'Don't know how to build task 'environment''. So I'm guessing it's not running it in the same fashion as clockwork as it's unable to run anything within the context of the Rails application. Environment referring to the task definition within my rake file (I assume) --> task :get_updates => :environment do

Comment: Ah, you may need to do the `chdir` after all, since perhaps your entire process may need to be in the top-level directory of your app in order for Rake to know about the built-in Rails Rake tasks. I updated my answer to include `Dir.chdir` beforehand, and remove the explicit `-f` option.